# Determinants of mixed matrices involving complex and non-commuting Grassmann variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, noncommutative-algebra

I was working on a problem involving a mixed matrix of Grassmann variables and complex numbers. Essentially I found two expressions for  a so called "superdeterminant" of the below matrix $G$. At the moment I have the following resultant equality:

$ \dfrac{det(D - CA^{-1}B)}{det(A)} = \dfrac{det(D)}{det(A - BD^{-1}C)} $

where the matrices $A, B, C, D$ are constituent parts of the matrix 
$ G = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{array} \right)$

such that $A \in \mathbb{C}_{n \times n}, D \in \mathbb{C}_{m \times m}$ and B, C are matrices of Grassmann variables of size $n \times m$ and $m \times n$ respectively.
Using Sylvester's determinant theorem on the LHS, so that the dimensions agree, I have that:

$det(\mathbb{I}_{n \times n} - A^{-1}BD^{-1}C) = \dfrac{1}{det(\mathbb{I}_{n \times n} - A^{-1}BD^{-1}C)}$

after cancelling the ratio of $ \dfrac{det(D)}{det(A)} $ from both sides.

So, I have a few questions regarding this result. Firstly, I conclude that 
$ det(\mathbb{I}_{n \times n} - A^{-1}BD^{-1}C) = \sqrt{1} $.

However, what does this say about the $det(A^{-1}BD^{-1}C)$? 
Can I conclude anything directly about this matrix product from the result?
Is the determinant $ det(\mathbb{I}_{n \times n} - A^{-1}BD^{-1}C)$ always its own inverse? If so, why is this the case?

NB: the definition I've been using for the "superdeterminant" is the inverse of that given as the [Berezinian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezinian) i.e. $ \dfrac{1}{det(G)} $ is my definition of the superdeterminant.

Comment: Do you want to post your solution when you've time?

Comment: I will, perhaps later or this weekend.

Comment: Class ${}{}{}{}$